# datatables pagination, search won't work

Tags: php, sql, search, pagination, datatables

I just started using datatables and the instructions to initialize the table seems easy enough.

I am able to get the table to appear and all of the data is inside, however both the pagination and search function doesn't work.

Please help.

This is my code:

```
<?php
Include 'DBFunctions.php';
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.9/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <!-- DataTables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.9/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

                $queryData = "select c.*, o.officer_name from coa c, officer o WHERE o.persnum = c.importing_officer ORDER BY date_imported DESC";
                $resultData = mysqli_query($link, $queryData) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                ?>
                <h1>View All COAs</h1><br>
                <table id="myTable" class="display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>PO Number: </th>
                        <th>Chemical Name: </th>
                        <th>COA Date: </th>
                        <th>Quantity: </th>
                        <th>Plant Name: </th>
                        <th>Parameter Results: </th>
                        <th>Importing Officer: </th>
                        <th>COA Attempt: </th>
                        <th>Date Imported: </th>
                        <th>Pass/Fail: </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultData)) {

                    ?>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['po_number']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['chemical_name']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['date_coa']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['quantity']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['plant_name']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['parameters_results']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['officer_name']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['coa_attempt']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['date_imported']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['pass_or_fail']?></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <?php } ?>

                </table>

                <script>
                $(document).ready( function () {
                    $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    });
                } );
                </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/fqxyg2zy/. Most likely the link to JS file `jquery.dataTables.js` is incorrect. Also take `<tbody>` out of the loop.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Thank You! taking the <tbody> out of the loop works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `<tbody>` out of the `while` loop so it looks like:

```html
<tbody>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultData)) {
?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['po_number']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['chemical_name']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['date_coa']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['quantity']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['plant_name']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['parameters_results']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['officer_name']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['coa_attempt']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['date_imported']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['pass_or_fail']?></td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable the various options that datatable provide, for search and pagination you need to do this. 
You should check the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/options) for other available options

```
$(document).ready( function () {
             $('#myTable').DataTable({
              "paging": true,
             "searching": true,
          });
       } );
```

Comment: That's incorrect, these options are enabled by default, no need to explicitly enable them.